# Integrate nodejs with ruby for payment processing

Tags: ruby, node.js, activemerchant

I'm building a new website from scratch (no legacy code) that is basically a blog/wiki/forum/ecommerce kind of thing, but I have a lot of custom things I want, and I'm willing to put in the effort to build them when I have to. I'm not really satisfied with the shopping carts out there, I don't want to use php, and I think there are a lot of great new technologies I'd like to use with my eye on the future. Specifically, I'd like to use Node.js and MongoDB.

My big sticking point that is holding me back right now is payment processing. I know that there is a library for node.js to do payment processing, but I'm too worried about its stability right now. I'm willing to deal with some possible bugs/stability serving up a blog post, but I do not want to screw around when it comes to credit card data, etc.

My current thinking is that my best compromise right now is to maybe leverage Ruby's Active Merchant to do just the payment processing. My question is: what is the best way to perform this integration, and does it even seem like a good idea? Do I need to set up a whole web server with rails hidden behind node or another proxy, or is there something simpler to just accomplish the payment processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pursued the ruby integration solution by [asking another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902502/node-js-ruby-integration-with-beanstalkd) about using beanstalkd for sending off payment processing jobs. In the end I have decided on trying to use redis instead to communicate with ruby using pub/sub.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [How to setup Stripe payments with node.js](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/stripe-payments-with-node/)?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like: http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/ — It'll make your life easier.

Comment: How does this help me integrate with node.js? I don't see a client library listed.

Comment: Ok, so there is a client library in development, but they list it as alpha. Seems like a nice payment gateway, though.

Comment: I emailed braintree, and they said that they are not currently working on the node.js payment gateway at this time but may be doing so within the next few months. This isn't good enough for my timeline.